# How to set height and width of LoadingPlaceholder in CachedImage of FFImageLoading in Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, ffimageloading

I want to set height and width of LoadingPlaceholder in CachedImage of FFImageLoading in Xamarin.Forms.

I have tried by following way but the GIF image use full size and shows big. I want to make it 64px as it's current size.

Code: 
xaml file

```
Namespace: xmlns:ff="clr-namespace:FFImageLoading.Forms;assembly=FFImageLoading.Forms"

<ff:CachedImage Source="image.png" Aspect="AspectFill" 
        LoadingPlaceholder="Spinner64px.gif" 
        WidthRequest="375"
        HeightRequest="375">
</ff:CachedImage>
```

Tried with SVG but didn't get any effect

```
<ff:CachedImage Source="image.png" Aspect="AspectFill" 
        LoadingPlaceholder="Spinner64pxSVG.svg" 
        WidthRequest="375"
        HeightRequest="375">
</ff:CachedImage>
```

Can you please suggest me how to show original size of gif image or set height and width of it?

[image]

Comment: https://github.com/luberda-molinet/FFImageLoading/issues/684

Comment: @ColeXia-MSFT I have changed according to the example(Edited in question). But didn't get anything. Even image is also not visible. Can you please suggest me what should I change in my code?

Comment: I just want you see the author's reply.. You have to change the placeholder image but not in code ..

Comment: @ColeXia-MSFT I am sorry but I am not getting what do you mean by `You have to change the placeholder image but not in code` Can you please explain?

Comment: you can use the image file in SVG format,  it is not support to modify placeholder  size programmatically.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?